# mongoose expressJS update single field in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to build edit function in my web app using Mongoose and expressJS as backend, I want to update a single field in lessonLog which is an array of lessonLog with individual objectId, I tried it with the following code but not working as I intended, please advise. thank you in advance!

```
{
  Object _id : 601e7877cc4bc5047860831b ObjectId,
  date : 2021-02-05T16:00:00.000+00:00 Date,
  tempoMin : 71,
  tempoMax : 206,
  title : Khulau,
  intonation : test,
  phrasing : test,
  articulation : technique : test,
  notes : test ,
}
```

```
const studentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  email: { type: String, require: true },
  contact: { type: String, require: true },
  activities: {
    exam: { type: String, require: true },
    recording: { type: String, require: true },
    theory: { type: String, require: true },
    competition: { type: String, require: true },
    orchestra: { type: String, require: true },
  },
  teacher: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "teachers" },
  repertoire: [{ type: String, require: true }],
  **lessonLog: [
    {
      date: { type: Date, require: true },
      tempoMin: { type: String, require: true },
      tempoMax: { type: String, require: true },
      title: { type: String, require: true },
      scales: { type: String, require: true },
      intonation: { type: String, require: true },
      phrasing: { type: String, require: true },
      articulation: { type: String, require: true },
      technique: { type: String, require: true },
      notes: { type: String, require: true },
    },**
  ],
});
```

here is the query:

```
const editLessonLog = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Students.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        lessonLog: { _id: req.body.lessonLogId },
      },
      {
        $set: {
          lessonLog: {
            date: req.body.lessonDate,
            tempoMin: req.body.tempo[0],
            tempoMax: req.body.tempo[1],
            title: req.body.title,
            intonation: req.body.intonation,
            phrasing: req.body.phrasing,
            articulation: req.body.articulation,
            technique: req.body.technique,
            notes: req.body.notes,
          },
        },
      }
    );
    // console.log(student);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Cannot delete lesson log, please try again.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should using `$` based on [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array

so just try

```
const editLessonLog = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Students.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        "lessonLog._id": req.body.lessonLogId
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "lessonLog.$": {
            date: req.body.lessonDate,
            tempoMin: req.body.tempo[0],
            tempoMax: req.body.tempo[1],
            title: req.body.title,
            intonation: req.body.intonation,
            phrasing: req.body.phrasing,
            articulation: req.body.articulation,
            technique: req.body.technique,
            notes: req.body.notes,
          },
        },
      }
    );
    // console.log(student);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Cannot delete lesson log, please try again.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
```